# Generic CommandExecutionException handling in axon framework

Tags: axon

I have a fairly simple axon application that Im trying to apply some generic "catch all" exception handling logic to.

If I have a command that goes into an aggregate that throws some kind of exception e.g.

```
class UserAggregate {
    //... 
        
    @CommandHandler()
    public void on(CreateUserCommand cmd) {
       Validate.notNull(cmd.getEmail(), "Email cannot be null");

       //other processing
   }
}
```

Then when I invoke this command from the Rest Controller, then the exception is far away from what I would expect

> org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandExecutionException: Email cannot be null
> at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.ErrorCode.lambda$static$10(ErrorCode.java:88)
> at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.ErrorCode.convert(ErrorCode.java:182)
> at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.command.CommandSerializer.deserialize(CommandSerializer.java:157)
> at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.command.AxonServerCommandBus$1.onNext(AxonServerCommandBus.java:313)
> at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.command.AxonServerCommandBus$1.onNext(AxonServerCommandBus.java:306)
> at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onMessage(ClientCalls.java:429)
> at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
> at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
> at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:596)
> at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:581)

Granted the message is useful, however, this is not always a given.  This can be mitigated when implementing an ExceptionHandler like so

```
@ExceptionHandler
public void handle(Exception exception) {
   log.info("Caught Exception - {}", exception.getMessage(), exception);
}
```

This now gives me a stack trace pinpointing where the issue actually came from, however, this comes at the cost of having to write such an ExceptionHandler everywhere I would like to invoke this command.

Is there a more generic way to log these exceptions without having to impose the ExceptionHandler on every class issueing commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would point you to the [code-samples](https://github.com/AxonIQ/code-samples/tree/master/distributed-exceptions) repo, where it shows a way of handling it using a `MessageHandlerInterceptor`.

Quoting from the repo itself:

> One of the most common ways to indicate that a logical error has occurred and that Command handling failed is to throw an exception from a Command handler. However, if the exception is directly serialized there is no guarantee that the command sending side can properly deserialize the exception in question.
> That is why by default Axon Framework will wrap any exception thrown inside a Command handler into a `CommandExecutionException`.

In short, you are going to define a `MessageHandlerInterceptor` responsible to `try-catch` the command execution logic. There you would have your centralized way of handling the `CommandExecutionException`.